# SQL how to display group by results in columns

Tags: sql, group-by, count, multiple-columns

I used a `group by` by id and year in a SQL query to display the following table :

| id | year | nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018 | 10 |
| 2 | 2018 | 3 |
| 3 | 2019 | 108 |
| 2 | 2019 | 873 |
| 2 | 2020 | 42 |
| 1 | 2019 | 53 |
| 3 | 2018 | 423 |

Here is the SQL code that allowed me to get this table :

```
SELECT 
    id,
    year,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) 
FROM 
    "data"
GROUP BY
    id, year
```

But, I want to display the result by columns, like the following table

| id | nb_2018 | nb_2019 | nb_2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 53 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 873 | 42 |
| 3 | 423 | 108 | 0 |

how I can turn the grouping by year into columns ?

Comment: Where is your code attempt? if you show us what you have done, we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Seems you're trying also to pivot values by year and not only grouping. If this is SQL Server, you can look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
SELECT id,
[2018] AS nb_2018,
[2019] AS nb_2019,
[2020] AS nb_2020
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM tableA
)AS Source
PIVOT
(sum(nb)
FOR year in ([2018], [2019], [2020])
)as pvtable
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba28f05485f82232ad8d4c0088e10b96)